# Using Google to search my GWT application

Tags: java, gwt, search

Is it possible to include a Google custom search on a GWT site:

- To search for keywords that is contained in GWT pages or views?
- Considering that GWT apps generate pages dynamically
- If this is posible, then what are the things to consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can with the Ajax Search for Google API, it has a high compatibility with Gwt:

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/AJAXSearchGettingStarted

You can use it not only for local search but also extends the capabilities of your Gwt Application, highly reccomended and very useful, hope it helps you.

Best regards.

Comment: Isn't this just the Google search API used in GWT to do "web search". I need to do search on my own site "pages" or "views", not really do web search...